# Describing an object that derives from multiple interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++, I have two pure abstract classes (Viewable and Movable) with possibly many types that derive (Dog, Duck, Cat) from the one or both of interfaces.

I'd like to define a function that takes a single parameter, where the parameter implements both interfaces. As far as I know, in C++, an object can have only one static class, so I'm trying to think of different ways to solve the problem.

Method `go1` below takes two parameters of Viewable and Movable. If I have a type like `Dog` that derives both interfaces, I can call `go1(d, d)`. However, I want to prevent `go1(d, c)` where `c` and `d` are different objects (with possibly different classes).

I can create a new type `MovableAndViwable` that derives from both Movable and Viewable, but this requires me to change the definitions of classes to derive from MovableAndViwable instead of deriving from both individual interfaces. Additionally, if I have many interfaces and want to extend the idea to more than two types, I will end up with a lot of the "mixed in" types (e.g., MovableAndViewableAndSavableAndRunnableAndRestorable ...)

So my question is: is there a *silver bullet* to solve my problem as I have described. See method `go3` in my sample code - I'd like a way to describe to the compiler that an object derives from two or more distinct and unrelated C++ classes.

Additionally, I'm interested in other designs for my classes and would like to now how other languages besides C++ solve this problem (assuming I don't need to use C++).

```
#include <iostream>

struct Movable { virtual void move() const = 0; };
struct Viewable { virtual void view() const = 0; };
struct MovableAndViewable : Movable, Viewable {};

struct Dog : virtual Movable, virtual Viewable {
    void move() const { std::cout << "Moving\n"; }
    void view() const { std::cout << "Viewing\n"; }
};
struct Duck : virtual Movable, virtual Viewable {
    void move() const { std::cout << "Moving\n"; }
    void view() const { std::cout << "Viewing\n"; }
};
struct Cat : virtual MovableAndViewable {
    void move() const { std::cout << "Moving\n"; }
    void view() const { std::cout << "Viewing\n"; }
};
struct Fish : virtual Movable {
    void move() const { std::cout << "Moving\n"; }
};

void go1(Movable const &m, Viewable const &v) { m.move(); v.view(); }
void go2(MovableAndViewable const &mv) { mv.move(); mv.view(); }
//void go3(Movable and Viewable const &mv) { mv.move(); mv.view(); }

int main()
{
    Dog d;
    Cat c;
    Fish f;

    go1(d, d);
    //go1(f, f); // Nope, Fish isn't Viewable
    //go2(d);
    go1(c, c);
    go2(c);
    //go3(d);
    //go3(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following approach. It seems to meet your desired goal of passing a single parameter:

```
class Movable {
public:
    virtual void move()=0;
};

class Viewable {
public:
    virtual void view()=0;
};

// A stub class, used for parameter passing.

class MovableAndViewable {

public:
    Movable &m;
    Viewable &v;

public:
    template<typename m_and_v> MovableAndViewable(m_and_v &object)
        : m(object), v(object)
    {
    }
};

// Passing only a single parameter:    
void go2(const MovableAndViewable &mv)
{
    mv.m.move();
    mv.v.view();
}

// Example:

class MV : public Movable, public Viewable {

public:

    void move()
    {
    }

    void view()
    {
    }
};

void go3()
{
    MV mv;

    go2(mv);
}
```

Then, additionally I would also declare:

```
class const_MovableAndViewable {

public:
    const Movable &m;
    const Viewable &v;

public:
    template<typename m_and_v> const_MovableAndViewable(const m_and_v &object)
        : m(object), v(object)
    {
    }
};

// In order to be able to pass references to const objects:

void const_go2(const const_MovableAndViewable &mv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic casting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). This lets you access any type your instance inherits.

It might be useful to have a more generic base class so that you don't have to choose between your interfaces when designing your functions (`base` is a commonly used type name).

Comment: The problem with dynamic casting is that it makes it possible to pass instances of classes that do not implement both interfaces, and figure it out only at runtime. Ideally, you want the compiler to reject the code.